# OpenCV change path and permissions in function cvSave

Tags: opencv, exception, haar-classifier

How can I change the path and permissions of cvSave in OpenCV?

I am doing a haartraining and after all stages are complete I receive an error:

```
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (Could not open the file storage. Check the path and permissions) in cvSave, file /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_graphics_opencv/opencv/work/opencv-2.4.9/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp, line 5036

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_mports_dports_graphics_opencv/opencv/work/opencv-2.4.9/modules/core/src/persistence.cpp:5036: error: (-2) Could not open the file storage. Check the path and permissions in function cvSave
```

The issue seems to be with the path and permissions in the function cvSave, but I am unsure how to change these, or what is wrong with them.  Any help fixing this is appreciated.

Comment: Without the code showing oow cvSave() was called, it is difficult to guess what might be wrong. All I know is that cvOpenFileStorage() can't open the filename you supplied for writing. That could be because the filename you provided includes  a path that does not exist, or the particular folder/directory does not have write permission. What platform is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by moving all of the intermediate files to a new directory and changed the command to use that directory instead. Seems that it had to do with write permission in that directory.